# Using find on multiple file extensions in combination with grep

Tags: bash, shell

I am having a problems using find and grep together in msys on Windows.  However, I also tried the same command on a Linux machine and it behaved the same.  Notwithstanding, the syntax below is for windows in that the semicolon on the end of the command is not preceded by a backslash.

I am trying to write a find expression to find *.cpp and *.h files and pass the results to grep.  If I run this alone, it successfully finds all the .cpp and .h files:

```
find . -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h'
```

But if I add in an exec grep expression like this:

```
find . -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h' -exec grep -l 'std::deque' {} ;
```

It only greps the .h files.  If I switch the .h and .cpp order in the command, it only searches the .h.  Essentially, it appears to only grep the last file extension in the expression.  What do I need to do to grep both .h and .cpp??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `-o`, you will need to use parentheses around it:

```
find . \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h' \) -exec grep -l 'std::deque' {} \;
```

Comment: I tried the parenthesis like you showed above before I posted the question but I didn't put a an extra space between the expression and the parenthesis like you did.  The extra space appears to make all the difference.  I had no idea I needed the extra spaces.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Or.. you can ...

```
bash$> grep '/bin' `find . -name "*.pl" -o -name "*.sh"`

./a.sh:#!/bin/bash
./pop3.pl:#!/usr/bin/perl
./seek.pl:#!/usr/bin/perl -w
./move.sh:#!/bin/bash

bash$>
```

Above command greps 'bin' in "*.sh" and "*.pl" files. And it has found them !!